# swipe js how to use API

Tags: reactjs, api, swipe

I am trying to learn react by doing and i got stuck.
I'm trying to make a simple app with carousel slider using swipe js library (https://github.com/lyfeyaj/swipe), but i can't figure out how to use API of Swipe.

I have made example on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-herschel-lhf8c

Could someone please help me understand that by showing how to use API to switch to 3rd slide whenever i click on button "3"? 
Thanks for all help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `swipeEl.slide(2);`. Even better, you can pass slide index to `buttonClick` so you can reuse `buttonClick` in multiple buttons.

Documentation for react version is [here](https://github.com/lyfeyaj/swipe/tree/master/react)

N.B. this is [another example](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-sunset-mwxwm) how you can use `ref`: